# How do I check the up time in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [See computer’s uptime and history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50815/see-computers-uptime-and-history)

Well sometimes for testing purposes I want to know the up time but don't know where to look. How do I check for this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A simple way is to use the command `uptime`.

Example:

```
$ uptime 
 15:26:58 up  2:34,  3 users,  load average: 0.27, 0.28, 0.30
```

That means it's now 15:26 and my computer has been up for 2:34 hours.

If you prefer a desktop program, there are several that can show the up time, for example [Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) or [GKrellM](http://freecode.com/projects/gkrellm).

Conky (screenshot from the Conky web site):

[image]

GKrellM:

[image]