# Is there a way I can get the time since my comptuer last booted?

Tags: logs, uptime

Is there a log file I can see or command I can issue that will tell me how long my computer has been running since last time I booted or logged in under my account? I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: There is a general question with answer on AU that has all of the commands and log files you can use. 1 moment.  Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50815/see-computers-uptime-and-history

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the terminal and run the 'uptime' command.